# Вложенные компоненты не видят переменные CSS

Tags: css3, vue.js

Фреймворк Vue. Есть следующая картина вложенности компонентов App -> Slider -> Slide.
Так же есть файл `variables.css` который подключен в App. Во всех стилях стоит `scoped`. Вопрос такой, почему вложенные компоненты не видят `variables.css`? И как сделать так, чтобы можно было подключить один раз для всех компонентов, а не добавлять в каждый через `@import`?

Внутренности `package.json`

```
    {
    "name": "test-api",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
        "vue": "^2.6.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.0",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "eslint": "^5.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
        "postcss-font-magician": "^2.2.1",
        "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
        "postcss-mixins": "^6.2.1",
        "postcss-nested": "^4.1.2",
        "postcss-simple-vars": "^5.0.2",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "vue-awesome": "^3.4.0",
        "vue-awesome-swiper": "^3.1.3",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
        "vue-slick": "^1.1.15",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "root": true,
        "env": {
            "node": true
        },
        "extends": [
            "plugin:vue/essential",
            "eslint:recommended"
        ],
        "rules": {},
        "parserOptions": {
            "parser": "babel-eslint"
        }
    },
    "postcss": {
        "plugins": {
            "postcss-import": {},
            "postcss-font-magician": {},
            "postcss-mixins": {},
            "postcss-simple-vars": {},
            "postcss-nested": {},
            "postcss-cssnext": {}
        }
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "> 1%",
        "last 2 versions",
        "not ie <= 8"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Если вы используете `webpack` или `vue-loader`, то импортируйте файл в `main.js`, тогда он должен быть глобальным для всех компонентов.

Comment: Сделайте импорт но не scoped и он подтянется везде

Comment: @RuslanSemenov, убрал везде scoped и сделал импорт в `App.vue`, не помогло, также пробовал подключать в `main.js`. На всякий случай выложу содержимое package.json

Comment: Не нужен он вы должны один раз сделать импорт в main.js `<style>@import '~путь к папке/variables.css';</style>`

Comment: @RuslanSemenov я вас не понимаю) Я могу дать ссылку на репозиторий, а вы посмотрите и сделаете пулл реквест, думаю так будет удобнее [ https://github.com/ornis1/onvix-clone/]

Comment: Так вы иморт используете не для стилей а для миксинов, тогда нужно использовать только импорт, только импортируйте через тильду `~assets`

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае так не получится. 
У каждого компонента своя область видимости которая определяется дописыванием хэша компонента в каждый класс, делается это в избежании наложения стилей с одинаковыми именами
Если вы хотите использовать общий файл для стилей мы можете убрать все теги `<style>` из каждого компонента, а в основном файле сборки просто импортировать его

В таком случае он не будет привязан к компонентам и стили можно использовать для всех компонентов